# understanding cakephp hasAndBelongsToMany

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm try to retrieve all reviews of movie with user model. i'm following http://joshbenner.me/blog/understanding-cakephp-associations/ tutorials.

```
$movie = $this->Movie->read(null, $id);
```

it returns below structure

```
Array
(
    [Movie] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => movie1
            [release_date] => 2014-04-10 00:00:00
            [director_id] => 1
        )
    [Director] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => direct
            [last_name] => direc
        )

    [Review] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [body_text] => body_text 22 body_text
                    [ReviewsMovie] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [movie_id] => 1
                            [review_id] => 2
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [body_text] => s body_textbody_text
                    [ReviewsMovie] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [movie_id] => 1
                            [review_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I also want to retrieve user Model also. so, i can display user name and other info. who post that review

Comment: I dont see any user table and its relationship with other tables in the examples what you are following.

Comment: I suppose you mean the user who posted the review. Then a review *belongs to* a user, and a user *has many* reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if im right your relational scheme should look like this :

Review -> BelongsTo -> User
And Review -> BelongsTo  Also to -> Movie

so the best practice is to create a new table ReviewUser called 
"hasMany through (The Join Model)" like this :

```
id
user_id
movie_id
etc...

ReviewUser-> belongsto -> (User, Movie)
User-> hasMany -> ReviewUser
Movie-> hasMany -> ReviewUser
```

NB : this is a good technique whene you need to store more embed informations in the associative table.

so you can now select reviews with the conditional statement FORM reviews WHERE user_id = xxx

see : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: i want add Containable, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define another relation on Review model.

## Review.php

add this relation-

```
 public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns Array
(
    [Movie] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => movie
            [release_date] => 2014-04-23 00:00:00
            [director_id] => 1
        )

```
[Director] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first_name] => direcot
        [last_name] => or
    )

[Review] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [movie_id] => 1
                [author_name] => dsf
                [body_text] => sdas
            )

    )

[UserReview] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [movie_id] => 1
            )

    )
```

)

i want it to return

Array
(
    [Movie] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => movie
            [release_date] => 2014-04-23 00:00:00
            [director_id] => 1
        )

```
[Director] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first_name] => direcot
        [last_name] => or
    )

[Review] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
```

['User'] => array(user array here)

```
                [movie_id] => 1
                [author_name] => dsf
                [body_text] => sdas
            )

    )

[UserReview] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [movie_id] => 1
            )

    )
```

)